# how can i make this gridview being returned from from a list of a futurebuilder searchable with a searchbar

Tags: flutter

how can i make this gridview being returned from from a list of a futurebuilder searchable with a searchbar, so i type youtube it shows youtube from the list

'this code returns a list of installed apps
uses Installed apps plugin
using a future builder, so i have 2 questions how can i add an if statement to make it not show an app and how can i add a search bar to this list
text to let me post
text to let me post
text to let me post'
text to let me post
text to let me post
text to let me post'
text to let me post
text to let me post
text to let me post'

import 'dart:typed_data';

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:installed_apps/app_info.dart';
import 'package:installed_apps/installed_apps.dart';

class InstalledAppsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  void Getapp() async {
    var aplist = await InstalledApps.getInstalledApps(true, true);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    late var aplist;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100),
          child: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Color(0xff707070),
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(
              "APPS",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
            ),
          )),
      body: FutureBuilder<List<AppInfo>>(
        future: InstalledApps.getInstalledApps(true, true),
        builder:
            (BuildContext buildContext, AsyncSnapshot<List<AppInfo>> snapshot) {
          return snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
              ? snapshot.hasData
                  ? Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          AppInfo app = snapshot.data![index];
                          aplist = snapshot.data!;

                          return Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                              side: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                width: 4,
                              ),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.blueGrey,
                            child: GridTile(
                              child: InkWell(
                                onLongPress: () {
                                  InstalledApps.openSettings(app.packageName!);
                                },
                                onTap: () {
                                  InstalledApps.startApp(app.packageName!);
                                },
                                child: FittedBox(
                                  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: [
                                        CircleAvatar(
                                            child: Image.memory(
                                              app.icon!,
                                            ),
                                            radius: 30),
                                        Container(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(1),
                                          child: Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                              app.name!,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 30,
                                                  color: Colors.white),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                            maxCrossAxisExtent: 300,
                            childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 20),
                      ),
                    )
                  : Center(
                      child: Text(
                          "Error occurred while getting installed apps ...."))
              : Center(child: Text("Getting installed apps ...."));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Item {
  /// App package name or Phone number
  final String id;

  final String name;
  final Uint8List? icon;

  const Item(this.id, this.name, this.icon);
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: im asking how can make this futurebuilder that is a grid list, searchable with a search bar on top, so if i type youtube it will show the installed youtube app